# Enumerate plots in matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib, title, enumerate

In a matplotlib figure I would like to enumerate all (sub)plots with a), b), c) and so on. Is there a way to do this automatically?

So far I use the individual plots' titles, but that is far from ideal as I want the number to be left aligned, while an optional real title should be centered on the figure.

Comment: As a side note, each axes actually has three titles (left, right, center), but I don't remember if that was in 1.3 or still just on master.

Answer (score 7):

```
import string
from itertools import cycle
from six.moves import zip

def label_axes(fig, labels=None, loc=None, **kwargs):
    """
    Walks through axes and labels each.

    kwargs are collected and passed to `annotate`

    Parameters
    ----------
    fig : Figure
         Figure object to work on

    labels : iterable or None
        iterable of strings to use to label the axes.
        If None, lower case letters are used.

    loc : len=2 tuple of floats
        Where to put the label in axes-fraction units
    """
    if labels is None:
        labels = string.ascii_lowercase

    # re-use labels rather than stop labeling
    labels = cycle(labels)
    if loc is None:
        loc = (.9, .9)
    for ax, lab in zip(fig.axes, labels):
        ax.annotate(lab, xy=loc,
                    xycoords='axes fraction',
                    **kwargs)
```

example usage:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(3, 3)
label_axes(fig, ha='right')
plt.draw()

fig, ax_lst = plt.subplots(3, 3)
label_axes(fig, ha='left')
plt.draw()
```

This seems useful enough to me that I put this in a gist : https://gist.github.com/tacaswell/9643166

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function to do this automatically, where the label is introduced as a legend:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def setlabel(ax, label, loc=2, borderpad=0.6, **kwargs):
    legend = ax.get_legend()
    if legend:
        ax.add_artist(legend)
    line, = ax.plot(numpy.NaN,numpy.NaN,color='none',label=label)
    label_legend = ax.legend(handles=[line],loc=loc,handlelength=0,handleheight=0,handletextpad=0,borderaxespad=0,borderpad=borderpad,frameon=False,**kwargs)
    label_legend.remove()
    ax.add_artist(label_legend)
    line.remove()

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1,2],[1,2])
setlabel(ax, '(a)')
plt.show()
```

The location of the label can be controlled with `loc` argument, the distance to the axis can be controlled with `borderpad` argument (negative value pushes the label to be outside the figure), and other options available to `legend` also can be used, such as `fontsize`. The above script gives such figure:
[image: setlabel]

Answer (score 0):

A super quick way to do this is to take advantage of the fact that `chr()` casts integers to characters. Since [a-z fall in the range 97-122](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters), one can do the following:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,axs = plt.subplots(2,2)
for i,ax in enumerate(axs.flat, start=97):
  ax.plot([0,1],[0,1])
  ax.text(0.05,0.9,chr(i)+')', transform=ax.transAxes)
```

which produces:

[image: subplots]